# My fragment doesn't play video/audio links

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
   package com.mixlr.www.oco;

   import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
   import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.media.MediaPlayer;
   import android.widget.MediaController;
   import android.widget.VideoView;

   import static com.mixlr.www.beachradioco.R.layout.fragment_listen;


   public class ListenFragment extends Fragment {

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(fragment_listen,
                   container, false);

           VideoView videoView = VideoView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
           videoView.setVideoPath("http://edge.mixlr.com/channel/wtrpf");
           videoView.start();


           return inflater.inflate(fragment_listen, null);
       }
   }
```

I am trying to play clip from the link. My fragment in android studio isn't play video/audio link.this s fragmet code please help, its xml file only have video view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code
**From**

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(fragment_listen, container, false);

VideoView videoView = VideoView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoPath("http://edge.mixlr.com/channel/wtrpf");
videoView.start();


return inflater.inflate(fragment_listen, null);
```

**To**

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(fragment_listen, container, false);

VideoView videoView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoPath("http://edge.mixlr.com/channel/wtrpf");
videoView.start();

return rootView;
```

**Update:** Make sure you add internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Bonus:** You can add a MediaController which allow you control the playback. These controls should include a seekbar, volume control and a play/pause button.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(fragment_listen, container, false);

VideoView videoView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoPath("http://edge.mixlr.com/channel/wtrpf");

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

videoView.start();

return rootView;
```

Comment: @SmartoDev show the code where you add this fragment to your activity.

Comment: it say can't play this video

Comment: now it is not giving any error but still not playing anything

Comment: I have a bonus for you, see my updated answer. Happy coding!

Comment: thank you :) i want this to be played in background when i click and go to other fragments. because this is actually an audio link